# usar libreria de C++ con Dllimport en proyecto asp

Tags: c++, asp.net, dll

estoy realizando un proyecto en asp net framework y tratando de conectarlo con un dispositivo de reconocimiento facial, este dispositivo tiene demos en C# con Windows Form los cuales utilizan librerías creadas en C++ y funcionan bien.

Pero cuando trato de utilizar estas mismas librerías en mi proyecto de ASP Net Framework me da este error:

**System.BadImageFormatException: 'Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)'**

El código donde viene el error es este:

```
[DllImport(@"HCNetSDK\HCNetSDK.dll")]
public static extern bool NET_DVR_Init();
```

Tengo la librería copiada en la carpeta bin, estoy haciendo exactamente lo mismo que en el proyecto de Windows Form y he probado en correrlo tanto para 32 como 64 bits, también he tratado de agregarlo al vínculo, pero me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que se debe a un error de compatibilidad, pero no sé cómo arreglar el error, he visto que algunos configuran iis para habilitar la compatibilidad de 32 bits, pero no sé cómo hacerlo con iis express.

Sé que puede haber varias soluciones a este problema, si me pudieran dar más de una sugerencia o más información donde investigar se los agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: Pero el dispositivo de reconocimiento facial donde esta? porque asp.net se ejecuta del lado del servidor.. y esa libreria va a tratar de ejecutarse del lado del servidor....

Comment: Actualmente lo tengo conectado directamente a mi computador a través de Ethernet tengo configurada la dirección ip y en el otro proyecto de windows form si funciona pero en este no